# Can I run tests in the same (constant) folder (to not create new folder for every new test)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

So I want to run the tests in the same folder each time (to not create new folder for every new test).

I really don't need to log test data and also I've got some xml from Nhibernate I need to move with it . It is coping to output directory. But doesn't work for test directories.

Really I just want to make all unit tests in the same folder. Is it real ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two question:

*Can you make VS to always deploy the assemblies to the same directory for the tests?*
Yes, you can.

1. Open the test settings (Test -> Edit test settings -> [your settings]).
2. Choose "General" on the left
3. Select "User-defined scheme" on the right
4. Remove the checkbox for "Append date-time stamp"
5. Enter a "Prefix text"

*Can you tell VS to deploy additional files?*
Yes, you can.

1. Open the test settings (Test -> Edit test settings -> [your settings]).
2. Choose "Deployment" on the left
3. Activate it by choosing "Enable deployment"
4. Add the additional files

Comment: The first part doesn't work. If you add some prefix text, multiple folders are still created. If the prefix text is 'Test'.  You will get 'Test', 'Test[1]', 'Test[2]', etc